# Can't get item with python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn how to webscrape with beautifulsoup + python, and I want to grab the name of the cinematographer from https://letterboxd.com/film/donnie-darko/ but I can't figure out how to isolate the text. The html for what I want is written as below, what I want to output is "Steven Poster":

```
<h3><span>Cinematography</span></h3>
<div class="text-sluglist">
    <p>
        <a href="/cinematography/steven-poster/" class="text-slug">Steven Poster</a> 
    </p>
</div>
```

within my code I've done soup.find(text="Cinematography"), and a mixture of different thigns like trying to find item or get_text from within the a and p tags, but ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex to parse the soup object for a link that contains "cinematography".

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://letterboxd.com/film/donnie-darko/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
cinematographer = soup(href=re.compile(r'/cinematography/'))[0].text

print cinematographer
# outputs "Stephen Poster"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same without using regex as well:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://letterboxd.com/film/donnie-darko/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
item = soup.select("[href*='cinematography']")[0].text
print(item)
```

Output:

```
Steven Poster
```

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS partial text selector:

```
soup.find('a[href*="cinematography"]').text
```